# Using TestNg to run a "Suite" of tests in Maven, Java?

Tags: java, maven, testing, testng, pom.xml

Currently trying to run a set of tests defined under a group/suite

Currently using mvn to run my tests so added the following
pom.xml

```
<plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>C:\path_to_suite_file_here\testing_api_suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and
testing_api_suite/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite STSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="uk.api.DataServiceTest"/>
            <class name="uk.api.ItemServiceTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

DataServiceTest as one example file

```
@Test(groups = "api")
public class DataServiceTest extends TestCase {
    private DataServiceImpl dataService;
    private DataDao mockDataDao;
```

However, when I run mvn test -Dgroups=api or mvn test it seems to not run anything?
Any ideas? Can provide more detail on anything just let me know
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add a sample project that can be used to reproduce the problem? That would be easy to figure out what is going wrong.